# Chrome extensions - локальная база данных

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, chrome-extension

Здравствуйте, господа!

Я могу с помощью

> chrome.storage.local.set
>
> chrome.storage.local.get

записывать и вычитывать значения по ключу, но мне необходимо создавать таблицы, добавлять в них строки, уметь делать выборку из этих таблиц по какой-либо переменной.
Что подскажите?

Comment: http://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Storage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

смотрите в сторону [IndexedDB](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/)